# Google spreadsheet and conditional checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I own two columns A contains numbers and B contains checkboxes.

If A = 0 I would like to auto-check the checkbox else I would like to let the user checks it (or not). But when I use a IF statement in the checkbox cell I can't check it myself (I lose its behavior).

I need something like :
`=IF(A1=0;TRUE;#keep checkbox classical behavior#)`

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

I don’t think you can accomplish this behaviour with a google sheet formula without compromises. This `auto-check` behaviour you describe can only be achieved with a trigger; activated when you edit a cell in column A.

I believe you need to take advantage of Google Apps Script and in particular use an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger.

### Solution:

Click on `Tools => Script editor` on the top menu of the spreadsheet file, copy & paste the below code into a blank script and click on save. After that, when you put `0` in column A, the corresponding row in column B will be checked. This behaviour will be applied to a sheet named `Sheet1`. Change that part of the code to apply it to a sheet with a different name.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet= `Sheet1`; // change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const row = e.range.getRow();    
  if(as.getName()==sheet && col==1 && e.value==0){
    as.getRange(row,2).setValue(true);
  }   
}
```

Comment: @NaziA thanks :) feel free to keep  your answer. I think it can be useful if the op or someone else wants this behaviour on a regular script

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do what you wish in one formula.  As you discovered, interacting with a checkbox in a cell with a formula is essentially like typing over that formula and would overwrite it.

My suggestion to accomplish this is to add an extra column and use the formula you suggested as the final check to what the state of that row should be (true or false).

```
=if(A2=0,True,B2)
```

Where A is your values and B is your user entered checkbox.

Here's a sample sheet with it loaded as an array formula.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z8A4WqVppcxGlGiM3l-kW6q88iYBE6LGw5PyVfRh9Js/edit#gid=0

You could then format that column as checkboxes, but if you use an array formula it will get tripped up when it thinks the checkbox is blocking the formula for each new row.